# How to call wordpress API to translate a post request

Tags: translation

Assuming am trying to send a post request for my application from wordpress. I know how to do that via wordpress function.

**Here is my question:** lets assume I want translate
a certain words in a variable to **German**. Does wordpress has a builting API that I can leverage or I should come up with my own php way via internationalization.

```
<?php

    $post_to_translate ="Hello am wordpress fans";
// then post translated data to database

?>
```

Comment: Are the word you want to translate post titles and post content or something else? Should the original text and the translation be linked somehow? Or should the translation overwrite the original text?

Comment: I do not have a choice. any options or solutions will be appreciated thanks  @Antti Koskinen

Comment: Hi, have you found a decision? I am looking for similar solution for my plugin and I want to take test perion API.